# Sigma notation start value

Tags: sequences-and-series

Why does manually adding to find S10 for the sequence starting at -8, with a difference of 3 (So -8, -5, -2, 1...) = 55, but using sigma notation = 57?

I can't write MathJax to save my life, so the sigma notation formula is here: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=summation(3n%2Cn%3D-8%2C10)

Comment: Notice that the second sum you've written *only* includes terms divisible by $3$, such as $0$ and $3$.

Comment: @T.Bongers Sorry, but I didn't follow you. Ron resolved my question with a formula, but if you wish to elaborate on your comment, I might learn something extra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write...

$$\sum_{n=0}^{9} (3 n-8) = 3 \frac{(9) (10)}{2} - 8 (10) - 135-80 = 55$$

or...

$$\sum_{n=1}^{10} [3 (n-1)-8] = \sum_{n=1}^{10} (3 n-11) = 3 \frac{(10) (11)}{2} - 11(10) = 165-110=55$$

Note that I used the fact that

$$\sum_{n=1}^N n = \frac{N (N+1)}{2} $$

Comment: Where you use n=0 and n=1 respectively, at the bottom of the Sigma, I had thought that area is for the starting value of the series. So is it better to use something like (3n-8) as standard practice and keep n=0?

Comment: @DavidMetcalfe: This is typically what I do when I am trying to match the sigma with the sequence.